# Fatal error: Class 'Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in

Tags: php, namespaces, phpdotenv

Hello guys I am so confused I dont know what I am doing wrong this told me 
**Fatal error: Class 'Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in**

But I dont understand why..

```
$dotenv = new \Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))));
$dotenv->load();
```

My structure is the next and in the file index.php is where I am calling Dotenv also I used use Dotenv\Dotenv; but it doesnt work too.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Be sure that you are using Dotenv **after** loading from `vendor/autoload.php`.

For example, I was using OpenCart, in which contained a file `startup.php` with:

```
// Autoloader
if (file_exists(DIR_VENDOR . 'autoload.php')) {
    require_once(DIR_VENDOR . 'autoload.php');
}
```

And I had defined `DIR_VENDOR` in `config.php` as:

```
define('DIR_VENDOR', __DIR__.'/vendor/');
```

So finally, in `index.php`, I would have:

```
// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

// dotenv
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

So `startup.php` loads `vendor/autoload.php`, which loads `vlucas/phpdotenv`, after which we can then find `Dotenv\Dotenv`.

Answer (score 6):

just remove/delete the `vendor` folder and reinstall with the -> `composer install`.

Answer (score 4):

with `"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4"` it now works like this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

or

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__); //Notice the Namespace and Class
$dotenv->load();
```

Answer (score 2):

check if you have "vlucas/phpdotenv" : "~2.2" in "require" tag in composer file. if you don't then add that plugin and open your terminal and run "composer dump-autoload" then run "composer update". and just to be safe run "composer dump-autoload" once again to refresh all the file paths.

and, if you do have phpdotenv plugin then add that plugin in "require" then just run the dump-autoload command.

Comment: I'm having same problem. Here is composer file.

`{
    "name": "auth0/basic-webapp-sample",
    "description": "Basic sample for securing a WebApp with Auth0",
    "require": {
         "vlucas/phpdotenv": "2.4.0",
         "auth0/auth0-php": "~5.0"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Martin Gontovnikas",
            "email": "martin@gon.to"
        },
        {
            "name": "Germán Lena",
            "email": "german.lena@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}`


Don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove `complied.php` from `bootstrap\cache` and it will works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me worked this code:

```
use Dotenv\Dotenv;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv(__DIR__ . "/..");
$dotenv->load();
```

Instead of this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv/Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the PhpStorm IDE and I installed dotenv on the server via SSH. Subsequently I didn't have the new vendor files in the local directory which caused this error. I simply downloaded the up-to-date vendor folder from the server (overwriting the local one) and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted vlucas and run composer install again. That solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

install vlucas/phpdotenv by `composer require vlucas/phpdotenv`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have composer installed

```
$ composer require vlucas/phpdotenv
```

if you arent sure about how to `$ composer require vlucas/phpdotenv`
try download from github [here](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Answer (score 0):

What helped me:

1. Delete `vendor` folder fully;
2. Delete `vlucas/phpdotenv` library from a `composer.json`;
3. Delete `composer.lock` itself;
4. Run `composer install` to initiate again `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file;
5. Run `composer require vlucas/phpdotenv` again to download the library.

It may still say `Undefined type 'Dotenv\Dotenv'.intelephense(1009)` on your code editor but on your localhost your project should load without an error. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path to autoload.php is correct
'../vendor/autoload.php';