# authorization of app using pinterest api php and create board

Tags: php, api, pinterest

i am using dirkgroenen library php for authorization of my app and create board 
which i downloaded from here 
https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP
evry time i run this code it gives me uncaught error about the line:8 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dotenv\Dotenv' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pin\vendor\demo\boot.php:8 
here is the code for boot.php

```
 <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require ("../autoload.php");

    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();

    $pinterest = new 
    DirkGroenen\Pinterest\Pinterest(getenv("4915445646307112766"), 
    getenv("1ae8683b277958bd9739cedb0f0b1434eee42176dd3d44cbf44981f9acaadd94"));

      if (isset($_GET["code"])) 
        {
          $token = $pinterest->auth->getOAuthToken($_GET["code"]);
          $pinterest->auth->setOAuthToken($token->access_token);

          setcookie("access_token", $token->access_token);
        }
      else if (isset($_GET["access_token"]))
        {
         $pinterest->auth->setOAuthToken($_GET["access_token"]);

        } 
      else if (isset($_COOKIE["access_token"])) 
        {
         $pinterest->auth->setOAuthToken($_COOKIE["access_token"]);
        } 
      else 
       {
         assert(false);
       }

     ?>
```

can anyone please help me to fix it.. i have spent more than 48 hours to resolve this issue..
any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: might be helpfull => https://stackoverflow.com/a/43235879/2940521

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you don't have Dotenv class anywhere where PHP expects it to be found.

Options:

1. You don't have it at all, then download it from here: [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). Composer should have downloaded it, BUT only if you used composer to install DirkGroenen.
2. You have it but it is outside autoload path - check autoload path, make sure that Dotenv is located in appropriate vendor-folder.
3. You have it but it doesn't support autoload (sic!) - check with latest version OR include it directly with [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

It requires [phpunit/phpunit](https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit) to be installed aswell.

Comment: thanks first of all..i have downloaded it as you told me .but again i found this error which i received earlier.can you please help me to explain your answer,because so far i can't understand what u said..

Comment: how can i use your suggestions in my code to fix my errors

Comment: @MuhammadHassan you need another additional library to make your code work. Download it and use in same way you used dirkgroenen library

Comment: i tried it using the same DirkGroenen libraray.. but could not be able to do so @iXCray

Comment: @MuhammadHassan did you download also https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv ?

Comment: yes..can i send you my code,if you have no issue??.might be possible my errors may fix if u could see it at least for one time

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan ... i already fix it.anyway thankx for your kind help